# jquery-sortable horizontal scroll to right it do not allows to drop li in target UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

i am using 
jquery-sortable.js v0.9.11
http://johnny.github.com/jquery-sortable/

It applier sortable to a horizontal li's .The taget UL is overflow-x: auto; It allows me to drop in target UL if i srolls the UL to left & drop the li at end of UL.

here is the Code i am trying

```
var sortable_ul = 'ul.target_ul, ul.origin_ul';//

var sortable_settings = {
   "group":'truck2job',
   "distance":10,
   "handle":'.dragable',
   onDragStart: function ($item, container, _super) {
      //console.log('onDragStart');

      var offset = $item.offset(),
            pointer = container.rootGroup.pointer

      adjustment = {
         left: pointer.left - offset.left,
         top: pointer.top - offset.top
      }

      _super($item, container)
      }
      onDrag: function ($item, position) {
      //console.log('onDrag');
      $item.css({
         left: position.left - adjustment.left,
         top: position.top - adjustment.top
      })
   }
   }

   //here i am initializing the UL

   $(sortable_ul).sortable(sortable_settings);
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please share working code in fiddle

Comment: Thanks @shyam . I managed it by adding vertical: false, in settings & making my UL's parent Div as display: inline-block. As my list is Horizontally aligned so i needed to add vertical: false,

Comment: Great: it means you learned new things by yourself. That's good.

Comment: Yep, ;) @ShyamShingadiya